# RedirectView.as_view V/s redirect

Tags: django, redirect

I tried searching documentation but I could not understand, is there any difference between the two or both these can be used interchangeably with slight modifications.
Or redirect is used only in the return statements. I tried searching through the documentation but could not find. Any help would be appreciated.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: The `redirect` *function* just returns a `Response` object that can be used as part of another view. The `RedirectView` is an entire class-based view *class* that is either inherited in your own view or used as-is

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectView.as_view()` is -- as its name suggests -- a view. That means it accepts a request as the first argument, it may accept some other arguments, and it returns a `HttpResponse`. URL patterns must either include other URL patterns, or refer directly to a view. `RedirectView.as_view()` can thus be hooked directly into your URL configuration.

`redirect()` is not a view, because it does not accept a request as its first argument. This means it cannot be hooked into your URL configuration.

`redirect()` can of course be used inside a view, which can then be hooked into your URL configuration, e.g.:

```
def redirect_view(request):
    return redirect('/')
```